# What is the best way to get a list of favorite articles by tags for a given user in django

Tags: python, django, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I have a question. Lets say we have the following models:

```
model User:
    pass

model Article:
    text, ...
    tags = ManyToMany(Tag)

model Tag:
    id, name, ...

model Visits:
    hour = Integer(number of hours since epoch)
    article = ForeignKey(article)
    counter = IntegerField()
```

In my client's local storage I have an array with the client's favorite tags.

My question is: What would be the best way to query articles with the following criteria:

- The first ones to appear should be those who are related to the client's favorite Tags
- Then, There should be the rest of articles, without repeating the favorite ones
- Respectively, they should be ordered by "hot value", which is a summatory of the 24 latest models' counter related to each article

I've put on my thinking cap for DAYS trying to come up with an efficien solution, but the best I've achieved takes entire seconds to query with a dataset of 10.

Please, help.

Also, off-topic, have I used correctly the expression "put on (one's) thinking cap"? English ain't my main languaje and I'm still learning!

Answer (score 0):

Use [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/)

hot value: `hot_value = Sum(visits_set__count,filter=Q(hour__gte= <one day ago>))`

belongs to user tags: `user_tags =  Count(tags__name__in=<user tags: List[str]>)`

use the annotations: `Article.objects.annotate(hot_value=hot_value).annotate(user_tags=user_tags).order_by(-user_tags, -hot_value)`

This will return articles with more tags matched first; if you just want a any tag / no tag behavior, you can use a 'Case' annotation instead.
Note that if you want to return all results and performance is a concern, you can move some logic python-side to decrease CPU usage of your database.